# .htaccess FANCY URLS not working within folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have a dev environment which will be the same as my production env, I need to create a FANCY URL that will look like `www.example.com/booking/{varible1}/{varible2}`.

However the code I'm using isn't working...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.+?/((img|css|js)/.+)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ ./index.php?varible=$1&ref_URI=$2 [L]
```

It just displays the `index.php` page as plain HTML with no CSS, just text...

Anyone have any ideas? My COVID isolation brain is not working properly.

FYI I don't really understand rewriting, so If you could explain what's wrong that would be amazing!

Comment: Well, what is the structure of the references to those style sheets and scripts? We cannot _guess_ that ...

Comment: Also make sure that you have `MultiViews` disabled and take care of the trailing slash that might get added to directory requests.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're probably using relative URL-paths to your CSS (and possibly other static resources). Your first rule looks like an attempt to try and resolve this<sup>***1**</sup>.

If you are rewriting URL requests of the form `/foo/bar` (two-path depth) as indicated by your rule and your resources are linked relatively in relation to `/index.php` in the root then the resources are not going to be found since they are resolved (by the *browser*) relative to the client-side URL (`/foo/bar`), so you'll end up with `/foo/css/mystyles.css`, not `/css/mystyles.css` as perhaps you are expecting. If you look at the network traffic in the browser dev-tools you should see what is going on.

You need to either use absolute or root-relative URLs (starting with a slash) or, as a *workaround*, set the `base` element to tell the *browser* how relative URLs should be resolved. Note, however, there are additional caveats with using the `base` element, notably with regards to in-page anchors.

See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters Stack that goes into this in much more detail:

- [Webmasters: .htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)

---

> ```
> RewriteRule ^.+?/((img|css|js)/.+)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
> ```

<sup>***1**</sup> Your first rule is attempting to *remove* the (erroneous) URL-path that occurs before `/img`, `/css` and `/js` file requests which could result from using relative URL-paths to your static resources.

This should not be necessary if you are correctly linking to your static resources (using root-relative URLs) in the first place. But trying to correct this with an external redirect is going to be bad for users, your server and potentially SEO.

Unless this directive is serving some other purpose not made clear here, then this directive should be removed.

---

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ ./index.php?varible=$1&ref_URI=$2 [L]
> ```

*Aside:* The `./` prefix on the *substitution* string is superfluous and should be removed.